# jquery autocomplete throws --> "parsererror", SyntaxError: invalid label

Tags: jquery, json, flask, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Following the [official example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete) for autocomplete, I came up with this.

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/search",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.username, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.name
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            },

        });
```

However I never hit the `success: function (data) { .. }` but always the `error: function (data) {`.

Firebug shows the error: `"parsererror", SyntaxError: invalid label`

[image]

The `/search` url produces this on the server side:

```
def search():
    data = None
    if 'name_startsWith' in request.args:
        q = request.args['name_startsWith']
        data = User.query(ndb.AND(User.firstname >= q, User.firstname <= q + u'\ufffd')).fetch(12)
        js = []
        for user in data:
            js.append({'name' : user.fullname()})         
    return jsonify(username=js)
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: my doubt is the username contains some invalid characters like a `"`.. can you share the character set present there

Comment: sure. `{"username": [{"name": "Kave Kory"}]}`  I dont see anything there though

Comment: your datatype says jsonp, but it is a json response, change the datatype to 'json'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the datatype to `json` because your response is a json object and the request is sent to the same domain so there is no need for jsonp

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/search",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        name_startsWith: request.term
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.username, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.name,
                                value: item.name
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (data) {

                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            },

        });
```

Demo: [Error](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NbLcx/2/)
Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/NbLcx/)

Comment: +1 thanks a lot. It works. But in your answer you have again `jsdonp` ;-)